# Read message from API response with 400 Bad Request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, response-headers

I have website on `React` and it calls the `REST API` to get/post some data. I want to display to a user an error message from this service in case of 400 error. Currently, it uses `try catch` and I can get only such message: `Error: Request failed with status code 400`.

I would like to display a proper message why it fails exactly to a user. So, I have to read it from a response header: `message -> constraintViolations -> message`, this message should be: `"Об'єм двигуна не відповідає обраній категорії"`.

**Service response header - 400 error code:**

> {
> "message": "{"constraintViolations":[{"message":"Об'єм двигуна не відповідає обраній категорії
> ТЗ","messageTemplate":"{ua.eua.validation.auto.EngineVolume.message}","path":"insuranceObject.category","translatedPath":"Об'єкт
> страхування.Категорія"},{"message":"Об'єм двигуна не відповідає
> обраній категорії
> ТЗ","messageTemplate":"{ua.eua.validation.auto.EngineVolume.message}","path":"insuranceObject.engineVolume","translatedPath":"Об'єкт
> страхування.Об'єм двигуна"},{"message":"Об'єм двигуна не
> відповідає обраній категорії
> ТЗ","messageTemplate":"{ua.eua.validation.auto.EngineVolume.message}","path":"insuranceObject.engineVolume","translatedPath":"Об'єкт
> страхування.Об'єм двигуна"}]}" }

**Code:**

*serviceOsago.ts*

```
const createOffer = async (data: IDataOsagoPost) => {
  try {
    console.log(data);
    const res = await instance.post('contract/save', data);

    if (res.status === 201 || res.status === 200) {
      return {
        success: true,
        id: res.data.id,
      };
    } else {
      const parseData = JSON.parse(res.data.message);
      const first = Object.keys(parseData.errors)[0];
      let message = parseData.errors[first][0];

      return {
        success: false,
        message
      };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('>>> ERROR: ', e);

    return {
      success: false,
      message: 'An issue when entering data',
    };
  }
};
```

*OfferReduces.ts*

```
const createOfferFetch = (type: 'epolicy' | 'greencard', data: IOfferData) => async (dispatch: any, getStore: any) => {
  dispatch(setLoading(true));
  try {
    const convert = new ConvertToOffer(data, getStore());
    const convertData = convert.convert(type);
    const res = await serviceOsago.createOffer(convertData);

    if (res.success) {
        dispatch(setOfferId(res.id));
        return null;
    } else {
        return res.message;
    }
  } catch (e) {
      console.error('>>> ERROR: ', e);
      dispatch(setError(e));
      return "Please check the entered data";
  } finally {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
  }
};
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Any ideas how to read such message from response header in case of 400 error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one help you

```
const createOffer = async (data: IDataOsagoPost) => {
  try {
    console.log(data);
    const res = await instance.post('contract/save', data);

    if (res.status === 201 || res.status === 200) {
      return {
        success: true,
        id: res.data.id,
      };
    } else if (res.status === 400) {
      const headerMessage = res.headers.get('message');
      const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(headerMessage);
      const errorMessage = jsonResponse.constraintViolations[0].message;

      return {
        success: false,
        message: errorMessage,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: 'An issue when entering data',
      };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('>>> ERROR: ', e);

    return {
      success: false,
      message: 'An issue when entering data',
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello! I have tried your code, it still reports: `">>> ERROR:  Error: Request failed with status code 400"` instead of the message from header. The problem here is that in case of 400 error it always switch to catch and I can not access the response header message, otherwise it will display `Uncaught in Promise` error. Is it possible to read the response header from 400 error code using `JS/React/TypeScript`? Thanks.